# Configuration of aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-listener

Tags: spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I have configured  as shown but get 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-
 listener'.

```
context.xml    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging        
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging/spring-cloud-aws-messaging.xsd">

<aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-listener/>

</beans>

In the pom I have 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have configured  as shown but get 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-
 listener'.

Comment: Resolved had the wrong namespaces

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
ht tp://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging.xsd">
```